# How to update Firestore Database using JS eventListener to submit form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting familiar with updating a Firestore database using an html form. When I hardcode `.set`outside of the event listener, it updates the database but when I try to do the exact same thing inside the event listener I get these errors that they can't reach Cloud Firestore backend and that XMLHTTPRequest cannot load the site due to access control rights. I have it set so that anyone can access the database so I don't understand why it's not working.

```
document.getElementById("pushMe").addEventListener("click", function submitForm(){
    let first_name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    let last_name = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    console.log(first_name, last_name);

    docref.set({
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name
    }, { merge: true }).then(function(){
        console.log("User saved!");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    });

   db.collection("test").doc("test_user").get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

   console.log("GOODBYE!");
});
```

Here is the event listener code that I am trying to use. When I take the decree.set chunk out of this function, it updates the database just as it's supposed to. We have an html form and we want it to submit on clicking the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form id="submit1">
    First name:<br>
    <input id= "firstname" type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    <input id= "lastname" type="text" name="lastname">
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="pushMe"> Submit! </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="web_app_test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone else encountered these issues?

[access control error??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh3gn.png)

Answer (score 1):

where does "docref" get defined? something is probably off with that

if you're trying to add user and you don't care about what the id will be, try:

```
db.collection("test").add({
    first_name: first_name,
    last_name: last_name
}).then(function(){
    console.log("User saved!");
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error: ", error);
});
```

using `.set()` is for when you want to manually set an id, a la:

```
db.collection("test").doc("manually set id").set({...stuff})
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!  Three questions that might help:

1. Shouldn't `docref` be `db.collection("test").doc("test_user")` since that's what you end up `get`ing?  Ultimately, I assume you'll want to set the doc ID dynamically, like `...doc(firstNameLastNameRandomNum)` so you'll need to save your `set` call to a variable, and then reference it via its `.id` -- but right now, you've hardcoded it as `'test_user'`
2. Is it possible that the data hasn't been set at the time you made your `get` call?  You might need to chain the `get` call as another `then` on the end.  Otherwise, I don't think your `get` will necessarily wait for your `set` to have finished.  (I could be wrong!)
3. Finally, are you basing your example off of this Firebase doc?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document   If so, I've often found that the Firebase docs will use shorthand that came from an earlier doc, like `db` would have been defined somewhere earlier as `firebase.firestore()`, so you may want to backtrack through those to see if there was some implied context to the sample.

Good luck!