# How do I change a firebase field according to a buttons value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 buttons, one to add 1 and another to subtract 1, but I'd like it so that it changes a Firebase field's value accordingly to the buttons pressed. How?

button and show code:

```
<button style="display:inline;position:absolute;left:45%;top:38px;" name="add" value="1">+</button>
<h1 id="count" style="display:inline;position:absolute;left:50%;"></h1>
<button style="display:inline;position:absolute;left:55%;top:38px;" name="sub" value="-1">-</button>
```

Code to update (I have tried changing stuff, but as of now it doesn't work and I don't know what way I should be going to reach my goal. Also, I followed a tutorial. I am trying to make 1 button add 1 to the "counter" field and another subtract 1 from it.)

```
const updateForm = document.querySelector('.update')
updateForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  let docRef = doc(db, 'count', updateForm.add.count[0])

  updateDoc(docRef, {
      counter: 2
    })
    .then(() => {
      updateForm.reset()
    })
})
```

Count[0] is coming from this code:

```
onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
    let count = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        count.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
    })
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=count[0].counter;
})
```

(The code is adapted to work for more than 1 field, but I only use 1. That is because I followed a tutorial as mentioned above.)

Comment: @MikeM added code now (sry)

Comment: Saying "probably very wrong" isn't really helpful here. You should provide your observations in the form of debugging details (observations from step through debugging, logs, etc).  What exactly isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: Where is the document ID coming from? Also are you trying to increment/decrement that value in database based on the button click ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have other code, I think it's more important in this part. And yes I am trying to increment/decrement the value in the database on button click.

Comment: Have you already checked similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905698/)? Do you see any error log in the console when you click on the buttons? That would be a useful detail to add in this question.